# XML resource file not getting copied in Android

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I'm developing an android project, and I want to use a <selector> in an XML file. I've put the <selector> in a file under **res/drawable/default_item_background_selector.xml**, and I'm referencing it with XML attributes like

> <TextView
>   android:background="@drawable/default_item_background_selector"/>

The XML attribute content I get from Eclipse's content assist, so that can see it just fine. However, when I compile everything (and it compiles just fine) and debug it on either simulator or on a device, the app crashes, with a root exception of :

> 09-24 23:55:14.771: E/AndroidRuntime(22478): Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/default_item_background_selector.xml from drawable
>   resource ID #0x7f020000

The **R.drawable.default_item_background_selector** gets generated just fine, but at runtime, it appears there's no physical file generated in the output directory. Has anybody experienced this before ? Yes, I've cleaned and recompiled (so many times).

Comment: Delete this file and create again with another name

Comment: @Alex Marshall Do you have any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
Created default_bg.xml in Drawable folder.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/red" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/yellow" />

</selector>

Create drawables in **strings.xml** is
     <drawable name="blue">#0000FF</drawable>
     <drawable name="red">#FF0000</drawable>
     <drawable name="yellow">#FFFF55</drawable>

And set background to textview
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:background="@drawable/default_bg"
         />
```